# Django Admin Login 'CSRF cookie not set' when deployed, but works on localhost

Tags: django, django-admin, csrf, django-csrf, django-sessions

I added several variations of the domain to CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS and CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS, and
ALLOWED_HOSTS. I added `django.template.context_processors.csrf` to context_processors. I had neither CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE nor SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE set to true (which I'm hoping I can change). I can't think of anything else I could do to get it to work on Django admin, and it only stopped working after I set up session authentication, (which included configuring csrf and session cookies). When I didn't have any authentication for the frontend, Django login worked fine, and even after, like I said, it was working fine on localhost.

I would really appreciate any suggestions on something else I could try to fix this issue.

Update: Now I'm getting this error message  `Referer checking failed - https://myapp.herokuapp.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/ does not match any trusted origins.`

I thought maybe the fact that it was a heroku subdomain was the issue, so I added a domain, and an SSL certificate. The new domain is getting the exact same error.

My CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS includes `https://myapp.herokuapp.com` and `https://www.example.com` and, because the slash kept being copied from the browser, `https://www.example.com/`. And even though there's an SSL certificate, I included the http:// version of each address as well.

Answer (score 7):

The error "Referer checking failed - ... does not match any trusted origins" is not related to `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`. It is about the `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` setting.

Make sure to include `https://myapp.herokuapp.com`:

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["https://myapp.herokuapp.com", "https://www.myapp.herokuapp.com"]
```